# JQuery doesn't see the first <p> but why?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am converting a string into a HTML DOM object with $.parseHTML():

```
var html = $.parseHTML('\
    <div class="row podcast">\
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 podcast_info">\
    <h4></h4>\
    <p></p>\
    <p></p>\
```

The rest is not very important, it's the two `<p>`s that bug me. There are a few dozen more divs and stuff and it ends with a '); after some thirty rows. The HTML code is solid, so I don't post it all here.

For some strange reason these references:

```
$('.podcast_info').find('p:first')
$('.podcast_info').find('p:nth-child(1)')
```

all return undefined. The first `<p>`, right after the `<h4>` doesn't exist to jQuery. They responds to `nth-child(2)`, and the next one to `nth-child(3)`.

Why is that? There is no other `<p>` in the block before them. Even if I output `p:first` to the console, it returns undefined. How is that?

JQuery version is 2.2.4.

Comment: Please show enough code for us to reproduce problem. See [mcve]

Comment: You gotta show us the full code. The above seems okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why isn't `p:first-child` or `p:nth-child(1)` doesn't work?**

[image]

It is because, `p` is **not** the `first-child`, while `h4` is. You might need:

```
$("p").first();
```

So try:

```
$('.podcast_info').find('p').first();
$('.podcast_info').find('p:nth-of-type(1)');
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  console.log($('.podcast_info').find('p').first().length);
  console.log($('.podcast_info').find('p:nth-of-type(1)').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row podcast">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 podcast_info">
    <h4></h4>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No real difference between `$('.podcast_info').find('p:first')` and `$('.podcast_info').find('p').first();`

Comment: Are you sure? p:nth-child(n) should select the nth p element, not simply the nth element.

Comment: @TamásPolgár True. `:)` See https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: @charlietfl Yea, I agree. But for some reason, it looks it didn't work.

Comment: But that's my point...why would `.first()` work if `:first` doesn't. Suspect problem is how OP is using the code

Comment: @charlietfl I have no answer. `:(`

Comment: Yes, $('podcast.info p').first() works. Weird... I still don't get why jQuery ignores the p: part from p:first or p:nth-child(1).

Comment: @charlietfl I said you right!

Comment: charlieftl:

This is your suggestion:
$(html).find('.podcast_info p').first().html('foo');

The original was this and didn't work:
$(html).find('.podcast_info p:nth-child(1)').html('foo');

Comment: @TamásPolgár I explained why `p:nth-child(1)` will never give you a result. There's no `p` element as first child. It's `h4`.

Comment: **nth-of-type** worked much better, thanks!

Comment: According to [this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) what @PraveenKumar says is right. When you're using the jQuery version, it gets all <p> elements irrespective of its position relative to the parent, then finds the first one.

Comment: Yes, sure! Thanks a lot everybody!